# Parse XML multi parameter

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a script that utilizes PowerShell to parse XML data and export to XLS format.  The script works when XML is not complex.  However, when a node has multiple properties, it does not.

Currently, to get a node properties I use:

```bsh
$Switch = $xml.DC.Rack[$i] | %{$_.NetworkSwitch} | Select-Object -Unique
```

However, I need to get Location, Address, and Vlan details.  Here is an example of what the node looks like:

```xml
<NetworkSwitch Location="ABC" Address="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Vlan="YY" />
```

Here is a copy of my PS1:

```bsh
$xmlFile = "D:\My.xml"
$xPath = "//Rack"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlFile -Raw

$NodeCount = $xml.SelectNodes($xPath).Count

for ($i = 1; $i -le $NodeCount; $i++) 
{
    $Switch = $xml.DC.Rack[$i] | %{$_.NetworkSwitch} | Select-Object -Unique
    Write-Host "$($Switch)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Select-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Select-Xml)? I didn't have a full sample of your xml document but this may meet your needs.

```
$xml = @"
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Switches>
  <NetworkSwitch Location="ABC" Address="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Vlan="YY" />
  <NetworkSwitch Location="DEF" Address="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Vlan="ZZ" />
  <NetworkSwitch Location="GHI" Address="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Vlan="XX" />
 </Switches>
"@
Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//NetworkSwitch" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

This returns the following:

```
Location                             Address                              Vlan
--------                             -------                              ----
ABC                                  XX.XXX.XXX.XX                        YY
DEF                                  XX.XXX.XXX.XX                        ZZ
GHI                                  XX.XXX.XXX.XX                        XX
```

These are System.Xml.XmlElement objects that you could store and manipulate at will. You could also further refine your XPath statement to retrieve only the necessary attributes. For instance using the above xml if you only wanted the VLAN info change to:

```
Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//NetworkSwitch/@Vlan" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node

#text
-----
YY
ZZ
XX
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to determine the number of racks first. Just call `SelectNodes()` with an appropriate XPath expression on `$xml` and select the attributes you want in the output:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//Rack/NetworkSwitch') |
    Select-Object -Unique Location, Address, Vlan
```

If you want the output in CSV format for import in Excel pipe the above statement into `Export-Csv`:

```
... | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```